# Error after installing Chilkat-11 in windows10

Tags: javascript, node.js, chilkat

I'm getting this error message, After i installing CHILKAT with this command line in NodeJS(version v12.6.0):

```
npm rebuild @chilkat/ck-node11-win64
```

> Waiting foError: The module
>   '\?\c:\APEX\Projets\PDF_SignElec\WS\Projets\node_modules@chilkat\ck-node11-win64\chilkat.node'
>   was compiled against a different
>   Node.js version using
>   NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67. This version
>   of Node.js requires
>   NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. Please try
>   re-compiling or re-installing the
>   module (for instance, using `npm
>   rebuild` or `npm install`).
>       at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:817:18)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
>       at Object. (c:\APEX\Projets\PDF_SignElec\WS\Projets\myExample_5.js:17:19)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:773:14)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
>   r the debugger to disconnect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to post this update.  The Chilkat lib for Node.js 12 is available at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@chilkat/ck-node12-win64

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild the binary.

Try the following:

```
npm rebuild @chilkat/ck-node11-win64 --update-binary
```

Comment: I suspect you will have to remove the folder from your node modules then reinstall. You can do this by first removing the package `rm -rf node_modules\@chilkat\ck-node11-win64` then `npm install` to reinstall everything

Answer (score 0):

Look here at the history of NODE_MODULE_VERSION numbers paired with Node.js version numbers:   https://nodejs.org/de/download/releases/

NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67 is equivalent to Node.js 11.*    The Chilkat module @chilkat\ck-node11-win64 is correctly built with NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67.

However, the version of Node.js you are currently using must not be Node.js 11, because the error message says "This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72".   You must be using Node.js 12.*.    Chilkat will be releasing for Node.js 12.* this coming week.

Comment: Hi Matt, 
I have the same error, even if im using the  NodeJS 11 or 12 :
- Error With v 11: was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67. Please try re-compiling or re-installing. 
- Error With v 12: was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. Please try re-compiling or re-installing

Comment: Is there any news? i still have the issue. Thank you.